# Old flags appear as "pending"

Tags: bug, flag-history

All my flags that were raised before April 2011 are marked as "active", except spam/offensive flags which are marked helpful:

> [image]

Checking some, they were obviously helpful (e.g. post deleted as result) so most likely the "helpful" bit was not recorded yet back then.

I don't think it should stay "pending" forever, better just remove it and put "status not recorded" or something like that.

Worth also to mention, this is causing a mis-calculation in the new flag history, as reported here: [My flagged posts count is missing one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268499/my-flagged-posts-count-is-missing-one)

Comment: lol I just discovered the same thing while going through my own old flags today.

Comment: I had some older flags (none that old) change in status recently after they made changes to the close review queue.

Comment: @JoeW that's right, the close votes queue got lots of attention lately and dozens of thousands of flags handled.

Answer (score 1):

Now these really old flags have a new home: "Aged Away" -

[image]

It seems that any flag over two weeks old that is still pending ages away and is no longer reviewable. This answer was created on December 27, the last flag to age away was from December 3, only 24 days old:

[image]

Comment: Nope. That's not what I meant in the question. I checked now (sorry for the too early upvote before checking), there is no change in the behavior described in the question. "Aged away" aka "expired" is just a status of flags that previously appeared as "disputed", as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Disputed and aged away are two quite different things. There is no overlap. Disputed flags are all dismissed by action of some user; aged away flags are all dismissed by inaction.

Comment: @Nathan I see. But still, the old flags I mention in the question do not appear under "aged away" (for me at least). However, the "pending" mark is now removed from them.