# My flagged posts count is missing one

Tags: support, flag-history

My flagged post count on stackoverflow is missing one.

[image]

I have managed to find the single flag by executing https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/83039?group=1&status=1

It is a very old one (2011) and has the status `pending`

[image]

I´m not sure if it is intended to leave this flag off or if the filter (pending) is missing

Comment: Your VLQ flag should have been discarded when the question was closed, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is really missing.

Old flags, probably before the point where the handling started to be recorded, all appear as "pending", as I [reported myself in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194803/old-flags-appear-as-active).

They aren't really "pending", more like "zombie flags", as the result is unknown, but they are neither helpful, nor declined, nor disputed, and not even "waiting for review". They're just there, without any known status.

Comment: I don't think old flags count as "pending" anymore. I think they just don't list them as anything, because my total for post flags is off by 782!