# Missing flag in flagging history

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

This is currently my flagging history in Physics.SE:

[image]

As you can see, 235+6+8=249 and not 250. In addition, I don't have any pending flag (so this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268499/my-flagged-posts-count-is-missing-one)). Where is the missing flag?

Comment: Did you recently retract a flag? [Those aren't available in the flag history yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283270/at-flag-history-page-add-a-link-to-filter-by-retracted-self-removed-flags).

Comment: @bluefeet Nope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this is a weird edge case and the flag involved isn't getting included in the total because your flag was invalidated by an event. The flag is listed on your history page, it's just not covered in any of the categories for filtering.

The timeline for this was:

- You raised a flag at Jul 28 at 0:07 on [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270274/work-as-force-distance-what-about-mass) stating it was a duplicate of [another post by the same user (10k only)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270267/im-told-that-nm-equals-a-joule-this-makes-no-sense-to-me)
- After flagging the post, the auto-generated comment was generating pointing to the duplicate
- About an hour after your flag was raised, the owner of the other post deleted it at Jul 28 at 1:02.
- Since you can't vote/flag to close a question of something that is deleted, your original flag was `removed during a deletion` of the post.

If you look at your flag history page, you will see the flag and the resolution of the flag. As I said, this is a weird edge case and we don't have a category for these flags to filter on. I'll look to see if this is happening on a frequent basis to see if we need to consider adding a weird edge case type of category for these one-off flags, but I doubt it's happening enough to make a change.

Comment: Maybe just "unknown" category?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Which would lead to the requisite what does unknown mean?!?!  It will be neverending.

Comment: Well, "flags with unknown category, e.g. invalidated as result of post deletion" sounds like reasonable explanation.

Comment: I like "weird edge case" as a category.

Comment: Need to see how often this is happening first @ShadowWizard, then we'll consider adding a category for this.  It seems like a rare event, but need to look first.

Comment: Sure thing, have fun looking! :)